# MDX using aggregate funcion member changes values of other measures

Tags: sas, aggregate, mdx, olap

MDX query that uses DEFINE MEMBERs gives different results depending order of measures in SELECT statement (when querying SAS OLAP cube):

```
WITH
MEMBER [measures].[someAggregateMeasure] as 
'Aggregate(
    { [FinalCustomerDecision].[All Final Customer Decision].[Booked],  
    [FinalCustomerDecision].[All Final Customer Decision].[LSO] 
    }, [Measures].[AcqTenorGrantedAVG])' 
MEMBER [measures].[anotherMeasure] as '[Measures].[XXX]'
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [DecisionMonth].[DecisionMonthYM].[All Decision Month (YM)]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
CrossJoin({ 
[ProductType].[ProductType].[All Product Type].[CL].Children
}, 
Hierarchize({ 
    LastPeriods(1,[BookingMonth].[All Booking Month (YM)].LastChild.LastChild)       
})), { 
[measures].[someAggregateMeasure],
[measures].[anotherMeasure]
})
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

gives other value of 'anotherMeasure' in comparison to query with inverted order of measures (note the difference is only in last lines):

```
WITH
MEMBER [measures].[someAggregateMeasure] as 
'Aggregate(
    { [FinalCustomerDecision].[All Final Customer Decision].[Booked],  
    [FinalCustomerDecision].[All Final Customer Decision].[LSO] 
    }, [Measures].[AcqTenorGrantedAVG])' 
MEMBER [measures].[anotherMeasure] as '[Measures].[XXX]'
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [DecisionMonth].[DecisionMonthYM].[All Decision Month (YM)]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
CrossJoin({ 
[ProductType].[ProductType].[All Product Type].[CL].Children
}, 
Hierarchize({ 
    LastPeriods(1,[BookingMonth].[All Booking Month (YM)].LastChild.LastChild)       
})), { 
[measures].[anotherMeasure],
[measures].[someAggregateMeasure]
})
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

The base measure XXX is a define member measure, not permanent one.
It is build with:

```
DEFINE MEMBER [measures].[xxx] as [measures].[a]/[measures].[b];
```

When I add a and b to query, the value of 'anotherMeasure' does not change with changing the order of measures in query.

I know that I do need to add a and b to the query to get measure XXX and anotherMeasure work properly
The question is what does AGGREGATE function MEMBER has to do with results of other MEMBERS?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Seems like pretty strange behaviour - try enforcing a solve order - does that help?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145539.aspx

Comment: Thanks, here solve order helps the same way as ordering measures in measures in the query.